# When to use android:Theme.Material.Light

Tags: android, android-styles

i have tried to use `android:Theme.Material.Ligh` in my `values-v21/styles.xml` and my activity extends `AppCompatActivity`, which android didnt allow and got error saying `'IllegalStateException:You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity`'
So i went through different threads on stackoverflow where people have discussed about this same error and i got little bit of clarity but couldn't exactly understood when we can use  `android:Theme.Material.Ligh` theme in our activity and when we can't use it.
For my app `minSdkVersion` is 15 and  `targetSdkVersion` is 24

Comment: try changing min sdk verison to 16

Comment: Change the Java inheritance from AppCompatActivity to Activity and use it

Comment: Just use `Theme.AppCompat.Light`.

Answer (score 0):

make sure `AppTheme` in your `values/style.xml` also uses AppCompat theme

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```